# Parameterized SQL UPDATE command causes Declare Scalar Variable Error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to run an UPDATE query that gets the new values from user input. As an excercise in caution I chose to use parameterization but the parameter in there WHERE clause generates an error stating `Must Declare the scalar variable '@WF_IDUPDATE'` According to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) the constructor `SqlParameter(String, Object)` should create a new parameter identified by the string and take on the value of what was passed in as the Object.

For you reference the schema of Table Being Updated is:

```
ID int NOT NULL
Approved BIT NOT NULL
FirstName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
LastName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
Title NVARCHAR(255) NULL
DepartmentID int NOT NULL
Department NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
TimeStamp DATETIME NULL
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
```

Here is all the code concerning the SQL Query

```
conn.Open();    
SQL_Command.CommandText += "UPDATE WFMembers_Staging SET" +


    "[Approved] = @Approved, " +
                "[FirstName] = @First, " +
                "[LastName] = @Last, " +
                "[Title] = @Title, " +
                "[DepartmentID] = @DeptID, " +
                "[Department] = @Dept, " +
                "[Timestamp] = @Time" +
                " WHERE ID = @WF_ID";


SqlParameter = ID, App, First, Last, Title, DeptID, Dept, Time;
ID = new SqlParameter("@WF_ID", 42);
App = new SqlParameter("@App", 0);
First = new SqlParameter("@First", "Bruce");
Last = new SqlParameter("@Last", "Wayne");
Title = new SqlParameter("@Title", "BATMAN");
DeptID = new SqlParameter("@DeptID", 1234);
Dept = new SqlParameter("@Dept", "Justice League");
Time = new SqlParameter("@Time", DateTime.Now);

SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(ID);
SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(App);
SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(First);
SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(Last);
SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(Title);
SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(DeptID);
SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(Dept);
SQL_Command.Parameters.Add(Time);

SQL_Command.Connection = conn;
SQL_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear that the SQL that is being processed contains a parameter `@WF_IDUPDATE`, and that no corresponding parameter has been added to the SqlCommand.

That parameter name is not included in the code that you share.  Chances are very good that the SQL actually being executed is different than that shown in your question.

Try breaking in the debugger at

```
SQL_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and checking the value of `SQL_Command.CommandText`.  Look for `@WF_IDUPDATE` there.

Also, double-check that you did not run the previous version of your program after a compiler error (i.e. check that your code still compiles).

Comment: Your explanation of the problem makes sense. Until about 5 minutes ago was trying to figure out how "@WF_ID" got concatenated with "UPDATE". It still doesn't entirely make sense but I know the problem was a typo in the assignment operator for the commandText. I typed += when it really should have been =.