# Gridview field empties on RowUpdating command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I currently am using two GridViews tied to different sqldatasources which both accept a value for each row using a textbox. When I go to edit and then update the other fields inside the row, the value which was filled by the textbox turns into an empty value. It was working properly before but after parametrising values as well as adding RowCancelingEdit methods etc it has stopped.

What is it thats making the 'Name' value Null?

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{            
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    String qry = "UPDATE [PlayerStatistics] SET [Name] = @Name, [Apps] = @Apps, [Minutes] = @Minutes, [Goals] = @Goals, [Assists] = @Assists, [Yellows] = @Yellows, [Reds] = @Reds WHERE [PlayerID] = @original_PlayerID";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apps", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Minutes", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Goals", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assists", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yellows", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reds", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@original_PlayerID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PlayerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="Please enter player(s) into the table." OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting1" Width="100%" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Name" >
        <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Apps" HeaderText="Apps" SortExpression="Apps" >
        <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Minutes" HeaderText="Minutes" SortExpression="Minutes" >
        <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Goals" HeaderText="Goals" SortExpression="Goals" >
        <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Assists" HeaderText="Assists" SortExpression="Assists" ControlStyle-Width="100%" >
        <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Yellows" HeaderText="Yellows" SortExpression="Yellows" >
        <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reds" HeaderText="Reds" SortExpression="Reds" >
        <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Edit/Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                <span onclick="return confirm ('Are you Sure?')" >
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"/>
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Update" ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges" Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="BtnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Cancel" ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Updated code**

Using a stored procedure:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //String qry = "UPDATE [PlayerStatistics] SET [Name] = @Name, [Apps] = @Apps, [Minutes] = @Minutes, [Goals] = @Goals, [Assists] = @Assists, [Yellows] = @Yellows, [Reds] = @Reds WHERE [PlayerID] = @original_PlayerID";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdatePlayer", con))
    {
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Name"]);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apps", e.NewValues["Apps"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Minutes", e.NewValues["Minutes"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Goals", e.NewValues["Goals"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assists", e.NewValues["Assists"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yellows", e.NewValues["Yellows"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reds", e.NewValues["Reds"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerID", GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["PlayerID"]);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `AddWithValue` is the value, not the data type. And since the `Name` field is not editable in your GridView, you can remove it from the update query and from the parameters. Your event handler would look like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdatePlayer", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerID", GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["PlayerID"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apps", e.NewValues["Apps"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Minutes", e.NewValues["Minutes"]);
    ...
}
```

You should also bind the data to the GridView and reset the `EditRowIndex` at the end of the `RowUpdating` event handler:

```
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
BindData();
```

Comment: I've changed the code to fit the e.NewValues and it returned this error **"The parameterized query '(@Name nvarchar(4000),@Apps nvarchar(4000),@Minutes nvarchar(400' expects the parameter '@Name', which was not supplied."** also by BindData do you mean GridView1.DataBind() as I am using an sqldatasource

Comment: Can you include the markup of your GridView in the question?

Comment: I've added it to the post

Comment: Which field contains the name? Which one contains the apps?

Comment: Wrong GridView, fixed it now

Comment: OK. For the name, you cannot get it from the `NewValues` because it is read-only. I will update my answer.

Comment: My answer should be OK now.

Comment: I've added the data key name code for the name value and now I get **Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".** as well as e.NewValues["Apps"] etc not working either, also claiming to be undefined

Comment: Oh yes, right. I don't often see a text query using parameters. They are usually found in stored procedures. Can you save your update query as a stored procedure? In it, you would declare the parameters `@Name`, `@Apps`, etc. Otherwise, you could probably declare them in you text query but that would look strange to me.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to do so with these values, seems overly complicated considering the update method was not affecting the name value too long ago.

Comment: Using a stored procedure is a good practice however, instead of filling the values in the text query. I can include the command in my answer, if you are interested.

Comment: Yes please, would this sort the problem of the name variable being cleared upon update?

Comment: I think so. My answer is now up to date. You can give it a try.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! However, I am still getting this error **Procedure or function 'UpdatePlayer' expects parameter '@Apps', which was not supplied.** after I executed the procedure.

Comment: Tough to say without seeing your new code and following it in the debugger. If you put a breakpoint in your event handler, what is the value of `e.NewValues["Apps"]`?

Comment: It says [0]  value "Apps" type Object{String}

Comment: Can you append (temporarily) your new complete RowUpdating event handler to the question? I think it is the only way for me to see it.

Comment: It looks good to me... unfortunately. The `@Apps` parameter is supplied, as are all the others. Only thing, if you manage to make the update work: instead of just calling `DataBind` after the update, you must use the complete code that loads the data (in my case, it often implies setting the data source). That's what I meant by `BindData()`. Except for that, I don't see how I can help more.

Comment: Okay think I finally fixed it, had to revert to what I originally posted and make the 'name' variable not read only. Would you know why this happens?? Thanks so much for your effort

Comment: In the process, I learned what parameterized queries are. Now, if you want to keep `Name` read-only in your GridView, you can replace `SET [Name] = @Name, [Apps] = @Apps, ...` with `SET [Apps] = @Apps, ...`. In other words, remove `Name` from the updated fields of the query, and also remove it from the list of parameters in your event handler.

Comment: I tried that already and it gave me back **Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".** so no idea what to do about that

Comment: As suggested in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302703/parameterized-sql-update-command-causes-declare-scalar-variable-error), you can put a breakpoint on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` line and check the value of `cmd.CommandText`, just to see if the `@Name` parameter rears its ugly head...