# Row updating wont work on GridView 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Team_ID".'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a table shown below that has two primary keys. Im trying to create delete and update methods that work with this GridView but I keep getting the error 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Team_ID".' even when I declare `Team_ID`. What's wrong with my statement?

[image]

```
       protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string qry = "UPDATE Membership SET Team_ID = @Team_ID, Player_ID = @Player_ID, stat_Appearences = @stat_Appearences, stat_Minutes = @stat_Minutes, stat_Goals = @stat_Goals, stat_Assists = @stat_Assists, stat_Yellows = @stat_Yellows, stat_Reds = @stat_Reds, Position_ID = @Position_ID WHERE Team_ID = @Team_ID AND Player_ID = @Player_ID";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Player_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Appearences", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Minutes", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Goals", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Assists", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Yellows", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Reds", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SportsData2ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Team.Team_name, Player.Name, Positions.Position_Name, Membership.stat_Appearences, Membership.stat_Minutes, Membership.stat_Goals, Membership.stat_Assists, Membership.stat_Yellows, Membership.stat_Reds, Membership.Position_ID FROM Membership INNER JOIN Player ON Membership.Player_ID = Player.Player_ID INNER JOIN Positions ON Membership.Position_ID = Positions.Position_ID INNER JOIN Team ON Membership.Team_ID = Team.Team_ID" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM[Membership] WHERE [Team_ID] = @Team_ID AND [Player_ID] = @Player_ID" UpdateCommand="UPDATE Membership SET Team_ID = @Team_ID, Player_ID = @Player_ID, stat_Appearences = @stat_Appearences, stat_Minutes = @stat_Minutes, stat_Goals = @stat_Goals, stat_Assists = @stat_Assists, stat_Yellows = @stat_Yellows, stat_Reds = @stat_Reds, Position_ID = @Position_ID WHERE (Team_ID = @Team_ID) AND (Player_ID = @Player_ID)"></asp:SqlDataSource>


    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string qry = "UPDATE Membership SET Team_ID = @Team_ID, Player_ID = @Player_ID, stat_Appearences = @stat_Appearences, stat_Minutes = @stat_Minutes, stat_Goals = @stat_Goals, stat_Assists = @stat_Assists, stat_Yellows = @stat_Yellows, stat_Reds = @stat_Reds, Position_ID = @Position_ID WHERE Team_ID = @Team_ID AND Player_ID = @Player_ID";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Player_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Appearences", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Minutes", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Goals", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Assists", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Yellows", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_Reds", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That question looked familiar to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488044/gridview-field-empties-on-rowupdating-command/36489661#36489661. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have two major issues:

1. You aren't executing your query.
2. You aren't assigning a variable.

The proper way to assign a parameter to your Sql would be:

```
command.AddWithValue("@TeamId", value);
command.Add("@TeamId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = value;
```

Those would be how you add a parameter.  To execute you would call one of these:

```
// ExecuteNonQuery
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

// ExecuteScalar
var value = command.ExecuteScalar() as int?;

// ExecuteReader
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
     while(reader.Read())
     {
          // Access via column name.
     }
```

Those are the bulk of your problems, a full sample would be:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
     using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
     {
          connection.Open();
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamId", 1);
          command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Example";
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
```

That would be the proper approach to interact with your database.